# Json data not being sent to php files roblox lua

Tags: php, lua, roblox

I'm working on a avatar rendering script and it works fine other than the fact it sends no data to the php file hosted on the web. I have a feeling this is related to how roblox lua handles variables/non-static strings since it worked fine when i used what i call static strings. Btw this script is for a version of the roblox cloud compute service from july 2015.

````
    game:GetService("ScriptContext").ScriptsDisabled = true

    local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
    HttpService.HttpEnabled = true

    pcall(function() game:GetService("ContentProvider"):SetBaseUrl(baseUrl) end)

    while true do
        print("Checking for pending renders.")
        local Link = HttpService:GetAsync(baseUrl .."/api/RCCService/PendingRenders.ashx")
        local data = HttpService:JSONDecode(Link)
        print(data.UserID)
        if data.UserID ~= "null" then
            if not game.Players.LocalPlayer then
                game.Players:CreateLocalPlayer(0)
            end

            game.Players.LocalPlayer:LoadCharacter(true)
            game.Players.LocalPlayer.CharacterAppearance = baseUrl .. "/v1/avatar-fetch/?UserID=" .. data.UserID
            local RenderCharacter = game:GetService("ThumbnailGenerator"):Click("PNG", 420, 420, true)

            wait(5)

            if RenderCharacter then
                print("Uploading the image.")
                print("B64: " .. tostring(RenderCharacter))
                
                local GatherData = {
                    ["userid"] = data.UserID;
                    ["click"] = RenderCharacter;
                }
                
                game:GetService("HttpService"):PostAsync(baseUrl .. "/Thumbnail/ThumbnailConvert.aspx", game:GetService("HttpService"):JSONEncode(GatherData), Enum.HttpContentType.TextPlain)
                
                
                print("Uploaded place thumbnail successfully!")
            else
                print("Render doesnt exist, something went wrong.")
            end

        end
        wait(4)
    end```
````

Comment: use software called postman, send http request to server first, monitor url behaviour first , your question has dependency having no clarity

Comment: You [can't enable HTTP requests through code](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/HttpService/HttpEnabled). You need to use the command bar or enable them through the UI. I think you'll run into a few other issues, but you should see whether you can actually make the network request first.

Comment: im using roblox cloud compute service, not studio